# Mule :: Pattern matching

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, mule

I have files in a directory named Test_123_dump.csv and Test_123_.csv.

Using Mulesoft filename-regex-filter and I want to ***ignore*** files having **"dump"** and ***include*** files starting with **"Test_123_"**

```
<file:filename-regex-filter pattern="Test_123_(.*).csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
```

How will I be able to include the pattern for ignore?

Comment: Try `pattern="Test_123_(?!.*dump)(.*).csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use a negative lookahead `(?!.*dump)` (or `(?!.*(_|\b)dump(?=\b|_))` if a whole word `dump` is meant) here:

```
pattern="Test_123_(?!.*dump)(.*)[.]csv"
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qO1qG9/1)

If the pattern is not anchored by default, you need to prepend an `^` anchor at the start: `pattern="^Test_123_(?!.*dump)(.*)[.]csv"`

If you use `\b` version, please make sure the backslash is not an issue by doubling it (some [reference](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/schemadocs/schemas/mule-file_xsd/elements/filename-regex-filter.html) says Mule supports Java regex where the backslashes must be doubled).